# How to uninstall individual Office365 components in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ms-office

There is [un]surprisingly little or no useful information I could find on uninstalling individual components when you install the full Office365 suite on your Mac.

All I want is Word and Excel, and want to get rid of the rest. Shall I just send the apps to the Bin? Thanks

Comment: are you the Office365 administrator? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745895.aspx

Comment: from the link I gathered that that option is for installing office 2013 and thus it's meant for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trash the apps you no longer want.

Office 2011 no longer uses a dedicated uninstaller.  See [this Microsoft support document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2398768) for more information.

Comment: Does that also applies to the Office 365 ?

Comment: It does, you simply need to deactivate your license first.

Comment: Marked it as answer, I trashed the apps I didn't use and nothing exploded. I don't get how Microsoft can get away with being stuck in the 90s and survive in this time and age.